# how to replace specific characters with different rules with python?

Tags: python, replace

I have a file and some substitution is needed: replace "，" with "," and all other characters not in rule2 with a whitespace, how can I do that？

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
text = text.replace("，", ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [regular expressions module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
text = re.sub('，', ',', text)
text = re.sub(negated_rule2, ' ', text)
```

where your negation of "rule2" is formatted using the regular expressions syntax (see link above).